# Rails - Using uploaded image multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file, stream, parameters

I'm trying to send in different http requests inside a controller, the same image. 
This image is previously uploaded and gotten from params.

So what occurs is that after sending the image in the first request (that works fine)

```
RestClient.post url, payload(with image)
```

The second time I'm doing similar request It crashes and I get the following exception:
`closed stream`

So what could I do to use the same image repeated times?
I figure that the file is getting closed automatically after the first call, I don't know why.

**EDIT**

At last was a Faraday gem problem.
I implemented the calls with Faraday at first, and I was getting the images with `Faraday::UploadIO.new(image, 'image/*')` which caused this problem, don't know why.

Now I've simply changed for `File.new(image, 'rb')` and it works fine.

Comment: You're using `ActionController::Live` ?

Comment: Not really, should I use it?

Comment: Nope! I just saw the error said "Stream Closed", which is typically the result of using the `ActionController::Live` functionality. Can you post your controller and/or model code?